# Google Spreadsheet long IF statement?

Tags: google-sheets

I have this statement:

```
=if(
F1B!D3="1",50+FLOOR(D2/10,1),
if(F1B!D3="2",40),
if(F1B!D3="3",30),
if(F1B!D3="4",25),
if(F1B!D3="5",20),
if(F1B!D3="6",19),
if(F1B!D3="7",18),
if(F1B!D3="8",17),
if(F1B!D3="9",16),
if(F1B!D3="10",15),
if(F1B!D3="11",14),
if(F1B!D3="12",13),
if(F1B!D3="13",12),
if(F1B!D3="14",11),
if(F1B!D3="15",10),
if(F1B!D3="16",9),
if(F1B!D3="17",8),
if(F1B!D3="18",7),
if(F1B!D3="19",6),
if(F1B!D3="20",5),
if(F1B!D3="21",4),
if(F1B!D3="22",3),
if(F1B!D3="23",2),
if(F1B!D3="24",1));
```

But GoogleDocs return me "error: Wrong number of arguments to IF"
What I'am doing wrong?

Comment: See following thread:http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/6eBTzNdLwuk

Answer (score 4):

You can't pass infinitely many arguments to IF. There's a single condition, a single "THEN", and a single "ELSE".  You need to "nest" your IF statements, where each new IF() in part of the previous IF statement's ELSE.  Something like this (abbreviated):

```
=if(
F1B!D3="1",50+FLOOR(D2/10,1),
if(F1B!D3="2",40,
if(F1B!D3="3",30,
if(F1B!D3="4",25,
if(F1B!D3="5",20,
if(F1B!D3="6",19,
if(F1B!D3="7",18)))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to apply too many IFs, far more than necessary:

```
=IF(F1B!D3=1,50+FLOOR(F1B!D2/10,1),iferror(CHOOSE(F1B!D3-1,40,30,25),25-F1B!D3))
```

Also do not append `;`.